# Node js backend calling a python function

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am in a bit of a fix - I have a node.js app running on my backend, and I have a chunk of code written in Python. This Python program needs to be running constantly in the background, and I need to call a function in this program from the JavaScript code on an API call from some client. 
I was thinking of running the Python program as a daemon, but I could not find anything on how I would call a function on that daemon through my javascript code. 
I have never worked with daemons either, so at this point, I'm clueless. I would like to know if something like this is possible. 
The only other option I can think of have is to switch to Django and maintain the data as part of the Django app itself. I could do this, but I prefer not to. I can not write the Python code in JavaScript because of its dependence on some exclusive libraries that I couldn't find on npm. 
If anyone has faced this problem before, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: On the start up script (assuming a Linux environment) can't you launch the python part too? Or do the processes need to communicate?

Comment: They need to communicate. Essentially, I want the JavaScript part to trigger a python function every time an API is called.

Comment: The Python program could start a socket server listening on a specific port.  I assume the function in the Python program needs input parameters so then the Node app can connect to and write into that socket. The socket listener on the Python end would then process incoming connections / data and execute the desired routine. Not sure about Python, but it'd be a couple of lines of code in Java, for e.g.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That does sound like something I'd want to do. I'll try working with python sockets!

Comment: Even easier (but a little less efficient) would be to make the Python program into a local web service (which, when you think about it, is just a special case of listening at a specific port :D ). Make it accept params through POST, and send back a JSON. Restrict it to localhost, if you need to. You can use a lightweight framework like Flask to wrap your Python function. You can do this very quickly (while messing about with custom protocols and low-level sockets can eat up much more of your precious time)

Comment: @Amadan thanks for your suggestion. That was indeed what I had in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example (with `pip install flask`). Assume the function is "is this a real word"; and the heavy prep task is loading the dictionary. Here's code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

# heavy loading
dictionary = frozenset(
        line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words'))

# lightweight processing
@app.route('/real_word', methods=['POST'])
def real_word():
    result = request.form['word'] in dictionary
    return jsonify(result)

# quick-and-dirty start
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=7990)
```

When you run it, you can execute a request to `127.0.0.1:7990/real_word`, sending your word as a POST parameter. For example, assuming `npm install request`:

```
var request = require('request');

function realWord(word) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    request.post(
      'http://127.0.0.1:7990/real_word', {
        form: {
          word: word
        }
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          fulfill(JSON.parse(body));
        } else {
          reject(error, response);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

realWord("nuclear").then(console.log); // true
realWord("nucular").then(console.log); // false
```

(Obviously, in an example so simple, reading a list of words is hardly "heavy", and there's really no reason to JSONify a single boolean; but you can take the exactly same structure of code and apply it to wrap pretty much any function, with any kind of input/output you can serialise.)

If it's just for your needs, you can just run the Python program as-is; if you want something that is production-quality, look up how to host a Flask app on a WSGI container, like Gunicorn or mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node's child process to to call the python script, you could even pipe the result back to javascript if you wish ?

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

https://medium.freecodecamp.com/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a

Javascript.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;


cmd = `python python.py` // insert any command line argument


exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
     console.log(stdout);
});
```

Python.py

```
print("Heyo");
```

Even tho this example only catches a single output from the console, you could implement a stream.

Comment: "This Python program needs to be running constantly in the background" - presumably because the program has a hideous start-up cost. This makes spawning a process on demand unfeasible.

Comment: Granted my example does not stream the outputs, it should be simple to adjust the example to stream the outputs. Still not sure how useing sockets would be a better solution..

Comment: Hey I appreciate your response, but this isn't what I need. I need the js to be continuously interacting with python. And @Amadan is right. I want to do away with forming humongous relation graphs every time I get a request (which may be multiple times a second, even).